# Objective c , delegates

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates

```
@protocol SomeDelegate
- (void) didSomeAction;
@end

@interface A:ViewController {
id<SomeDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) id<SomeDelegate> delegate;

@implementation A
@synthesize delegate;

- (void)someMethod {
[delegate didSomeAction];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
B *b = [[B alloc] init];
}

/*=========================*/

@interface B:NSObject<SomeDelegate> {

}

@implementation B

#pragma mark - 
#pragma mark SomeDelegate methods

- (void)didSomeAction {

}
```

B should send message to A, why this is not working?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) before asking questions...

Answer (score 2):

You need to set b as delegate.

```
self.delegate = b;
```

However the usual way to use delegates is the other way round:

```
SomeClass* obj = [[SomeClass alloc] init];
obj.delegate = self;
```

Note that Delegation is not a feature of Objective-C. It is only a design pattern!
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do, this should be correct:

```
 -(void)someMethod {
    [delegate didSomeAction];
 }

 -(void)viewDidLoad {
    delegate = [[B alloc] init];
 }
```

otherwise, when you call `[delegate didSomeAction];`, `delegate` is nil and the message is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Objects don’t usually create their delegates themselves. Instead `B` should create an instance of `A` and set itself as the delegate of that object:

```
@implementation B

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    self.a = [[[A alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.a.delegate = self;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to send the simple message to other class, can use NSNotification

In B class file

```
- (void)someMethod {
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"NofifyMe" object:self userInfo:nil];
}
```

In A class file

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didSomeAction:) name:@"NofifyMe" object:nil];
- (void)didSomeAction {

}
```

So whenever your someMethod will call, then your B class will just send a message to your class A to invoke didSomeAction. and in dealloc remove the observer

```
-(void)dealloc{
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
        [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: There is alternate way as well to **just pass the message** from one class A to one class B